# Keyboard shortcut to show/hide tabs in ST3 Win10

Tags: sublimetext3

I was reviewing several pages but I can not make Sublime Text 3 have a `hot key` where you can show and hide the Tabs quickly, read this [link](https://www.cheatography.com/tdeyle/cheat-sheets/sublime-text-3/) where it talks about it but it seems that there is no such combination, someone who could do it ?

Pd: I do not want to do it from the menu, i want is by keyhots

Comment: By `keyhots` do you mean `hot key`? (i.e.you want to be able to toggle the tabs on and off with a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: yes, is hot key. I want to show and hide the tabs by a combination of keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to bind a key to this, you need to know what `command` to use in the key binding. The easiest way to determine that would be to select `View > Show Console` from the menu to open the console, then enter `sublime.log_commands(True)` to turn on command logging, and execute the command that you want to bind.

In this case, that would be `View > Hide Tabs` (or `View > Show Tabs`, depending on if they're visible or not), which allows us to see this in the console:

```
>>> sublime.log_commands(True)
command: toggle_tabs
```

Armed with the command, you can select `Preferences > Key Bindings` and add your own key binding in the right hand pane, such as this one:

```json
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+alt+t"],
    "command": "toggle_tabs"
},
```

Naturally you can choose any key binding that you'd like here. Once you do this, the menu command and the command palette entries for toggling the tab state will show the key you selected next to them to remind you.

Note that if this is your first custom key binding, you want to make sure that you add the binding inside of the `[` and `]` characters that will appear in the file. If you have other bindings, make sure that you separate each binding with a `,` character.

Comment: The text `plugin rewritten command: None` when you execute the command from the menu means that you have a plugin installed that is blocking the `toggle_tabs` command from executing; that's why the menu command also does nothing when you select it.

Comment: You're right, a plugin called 'Sidebar Separator' was causing this conflict, the uninstall now works correctly the hot key